# Why am I getting this output for a static variable assigned in both static and instance initializer blocks?

Tags: java, operators

I was given the below code in an interview.

Why is the output 2?

```
public class Test {
    static int a = 1111;
    static {
        a = a-- - --a;
    }

    {
        a = a++ + ++a;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `static` variable `a` is initialized to `1111`.

Then the static initializer runs.  `a--` evaluates to `1111` but sets `a` to `1110`.  Then `--a` runs, sets `a` to `1109` and evaluates to `1109`.  The subtraction occurs, and `a` is set to the result of the subtraction, `2`.

The instance initializer (with the `++` operators) doesn't run, because there is no instance of `Test`.  `2` is printed.

Comment: nic answer i confused -- - -- operator

Comment: a-- is postdecrementation, --a is predecrementation and - is just a subtraction operator.

Answer (score 0):

To understand the logic, add below code inside static block and run:

```
int b = a--;
System.out.println("Now b is   " + b);
System.out.println("Now a is   " + a);
int c = --a;
System.out.println("Now c is  " + c);
System.out.println("Now a is  " + a);

a = b-c; //1111 - 1109 = 2
System.out.println("a =  " + a);
```

**will print :**

```
b =  1111
a =  1110
c =  1109
a =  1109
a =  2
```